# Set model by clicking on one

Tags: php, html, angularjs

When I click on a model I want to set a global variable to that model.

My model list is initiated by:

```
<div class="card-body card-padding " ng-controller="ContactListCtrl"> 
                    <div>
                        <div class="contactperson" ng-model="selcon" ng-click="setContactPerson(contact);" ng-repeat="contact in allcontacts ">
                            {{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And the model is then loaded in:

```
<div class="pmbb-body" ng-controller="ContactListCtrl">
                                    <div class="pmbb-view" >
                                         <strong ng-model="selcon.initial">T.a.v {{ selcon.initial}} {{ selcon.lastname}}</strong><br/><br/>
                                         <div data-toggle="popover" id="contactaddresses" title="Adressen" data-content=""></div>
                                         <br/> <br/>
                            Telefoon: {{ selcon.phone}}<br/>
                            Fax: {{ selcon.fax}} <br/>
                            {{ selcon.email}} <br/>
```

The first time I manually call setContactPerson(allcontacts[0]) it does set the global variable, but later when I trigger the ng-click it doesn't.

AngularJS:

```
 $scope.setContactPerson = function (el) {
        $scope.selcon = el;
};
```

Solution in comments below:

Each time ng-controller="Controller" is called, a new $scope is defined. By using nested controllers, multiple controllers can still be used.

Comment: `ng-model` only works for input fields, not for `div`, `span`, etc. elements, and you are using `ng-controller="ContactListCtrl"` 2 times, please paste your complete HTML

Comment: My complete HTML is rather a large file, I am using the controller two times because I also use more controllers in the same application. Yet, is that the problem here? Because when I alert($scope.selcon.initial) (yes that value can be set) it does give me the correct  value. So it's just a matter of binding the model, or updating it's view in the 2nd HTML part?

Comment: yes, that's the problem, everytime you use `ng-controller`, a new scope is defined only for that element. Even if you are using multiple controllers you can nest them `<div ng-controller="controller1 as c1"><div ng-controller="controller2 as c2">{{c1.someValue1}} - {{c2.someValue2}}</div></div>`

Comment: If you are calling the controller twice, each time you call it, it sets a new scope.

Comment: Ah! That has fixed it for me, thank you both for your answers!